# Textbox next to the RadioButtonList

Tags: asp.net

I need to create a radiobuttonlist containing a "other" option, and i have to put a textbox next to it. Here is what i did.

```
if(!ispostpage){
PlaceofWork.DataSource = workplace;
PlaceofWork.DataBind();
PlaceofWork.DataTextField = "WorkPlace1";
PlaceofWork.DataValueField = "WorkID";
PlaceofWork.Items.Add(new ListItem("Other - Specify<input name=\"OtherWorkPlace\" type=\"text\" value=\"test\" id=\"OtherWorkPlace\"/>", "-1"));
```

This radiobuttonlist is in a usercontrol.
at the first I didn't add `if(!ispostpage)` so when i try `Request.Form["OtherWorkPlace"]`, it didn't return anything

after i add the code `if(!ispostpage)`, it pop up the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

So how can I get the value of the input textbox?

Comment: Do you want to get the memory of this textbox on any click event ?

Comment: In my situation, the hidden field maybe more suitable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hidden field control on the asp .net side.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="rbOtherText" />
```

The set the value of the control using a javascript onblur event.

```
 PlaceofWork.Items.Add(new ListItem("Other - Specify<input name=\"OtherWorkPlace\" type=\"text\" value=\"test\" onblur=\"document.getElementById('" & rbOtherText.ClientID & "').value = this.value;\" />", "-1"));
```

Then in the code behind just reference the HiddenField.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this would help you out, but wouldn't it help if you place a asp:TextBox control in the page and retrieve the value from it only if 'Other' radio button is checked? This text box can be made visible in the client side once the 'Other' radio button is checked. The text box can be placed next to the radio button using CSS.

Comment: Yeah, i also thought about that too, but i don't know how to put the textbox just next to the "Other" option by using css

Comment: Since the 'Other' option is the last item in the list, would you be able to place it right under the radio button list. This way, you wouldnt have to style it using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The runat="server" is not buying you anything, it's probably just being rendered directly into the output. If you can see it when you View Source on the page, then it's not being processed as a server side control. I would get rid of that.

Add an ID attribute with the same value as the name attribute:

```
PlaceofWork.Items.Add(new ListItem("Other - Specify<input id=\"OtherWorkPlace\" name=\"OtherWorkPlace\" type=\"text\" value=\"test\"/>", "-1"));
```

Remember that IDs must be unique, so you can only have one of these per page without changing the naming convention. Then you are able to see it in the Form collection, as you previously tried.

**ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<%@ Register src="WebUserControl1.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl1" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" />

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ASPX Code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        string result = Request.Form["OtherWorkPlace"].ToString();
    }
}
```

**ASCX**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebUserControl1" %>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**ASCX Code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("1");
    list.Add("2");
    list.Add("3");

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        RadioButtonList1.DataSource = list;
        RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
        //RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = "Value";
        //RadioButtonList1.DataValueField = "Key";
        RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Other - Specify<input id=\"OtherWorkPlace\" name=\"OtherWorkPlace\" type=\"text\" value=\"test\" />", "-1"));
    }
}
```

If your RadioButtonList is in a UserControl, it sounds like you want to re-use this in multiple places, possibly even on the same page. If so, you are definitely going to have to come up with a way to manage the IDs so they don't conflict.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Request.Form["OtherWorkPlace"]) still got nothing

Comment: Works fine for me. See example above from VS2008 .NET 3.5.

Comment: OK, I think i found the problem, my radiobuttonlist is in a user control, and after I add if(!ispostback) it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object. any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you edit your question with an additional code example?

Comment: Thanks very much, i am very appreciate your help. there is just one more thing. In the main page which includes the user control, I also used multiview, so it has couple pages. When i turned to say page 3,  if (IsPostBack) is true, and if the usercontrol is on page 4, still error.

Comment: As you've already accepted an answer, I'll let mine stand as it is.